# Docker : Docker volume is not accessible inside the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-volume

I ve a container running a java process and  writing the java logs in a specific volume declared inside the container within Dockerfile :

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM myRegistry/jdk:1.8.181 
VOLUME /opt/logs
ENTRYPOINT ["java",","/opt/application/myapp.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=server"]
```

As you can see i'm declaring this volume `/opt/logs` inside the container .
(inside my java app , that folder is userd by logback to write errors )

But when running  the container , it fails after seconds saying that there is no access to this folder `"permission denied"` :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/opt/logs/myapp.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/logs/myapp.log (Permission denied)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:153)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:56)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:266)
        ... 18 more
```

I ve succeded to access the container before it's getting down to see the permissions :

```
[myuser@8d39ada92190 opt]$ ll
total 49100
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 myuser mygroup 50273298 Sep 19 15:57 myapp.jar
drwxr-xr-x  2  65534   65534     4096 Oct  1 13:52 logs
```

I noticed that the "`logs`" folder is not st with the normal user and **group (myuser  / mygroup)**  but with other strange ones **65534**

**Any ideas ??**

Comment: Show the Dockerfile used for building myRegistry/jdk:1.8.181 please.

Comment: @egor7 i don t think that's a jdk image issue , as i ve used it during years with other containers and i ven had this isse , also that image is a simlple jdk image taken from Dockerhub and then pushed to myRegistry

Comment: can you share you `docker run` command?